# Is it possible to keep a paragraph's width (desktop - mobile) without using media queries in css?

Tags: css, media-queries

Expanding on the title here. What I mean is, I have some text in a div that I want to have a width of 75% in desktop mode. The problem arises in mobile mode as the div obviously still has a width of 75% and it looks weird, it should have 100%. Sure, I can fix this with media queries, but it seems so unnecessary to waste a couple of line of CSS code just for this small fix. See images for further explanation.

Desktop version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4PAR.png

Mobile version:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpmOI.png

Mobile version looks weird when it's only 75% width. I'm new to CSS3 so I'm just wondering if you guys know of any better way instead of using media queries all the time and everywhere.

Example code:

```
<div class="birch"> A lot of text </div>
.birch {width:75%}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Fair point. But can I write anything in the same CSS lines instead of a media query, like a min-max width or something? In the same way that you can write "font: italic bold 12px/30px Georgia, serif;" on single line instead of separating them?

Edit: Comment I responded was removed.

Comment: If you had a hypothetical media query at `600px`, you can do `width: 100%; max-width: 600px;`.

Comment: Ahh ok! So just a lingering media query with nothing inside, and write the above code on the div class css?

Comment: You don't need a media query at all (if you're going to write an empty one, it's the same as not having any, so it has no effect). You can use the `width` and `max-width` combo on your `.birch` element, that's all you'll need to ensure your content takes up more space on smaller screens, but no more than `600px` on larger ones.

Comment: Alright! Makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, it's better to use `max-width` instead of `width` property.

For example.

```
.birch {
  max-width: 480px;
}
```

This will give you good aligned paragraph on desktop, and full-size paragraph on mobile. Yes, it's takes time to calculate perfect `max-width`, but it's also gives you a freedom of not writting any additional media-queries.